# Javascript: Using string variable to target functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an array to tidy up my code so that I can add a bunch of event listeners to various buttons.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < buttoncount; i++){
    var targetid = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].id;
    var targetidfunc = targetid + "function";
    console.log(targetidfunc);
    document.getElementById(targetid).addEventListener("click", targetidfunc);
  }
```

The console has the correct function names however the event listener does not work, how can I fix this?

Comment: what is your function?

Comment: why dont directly
`target = document.getElementByTagName("button");
target[i].addEventListener('click', function(){alert("OK")})`